# How to nested loop infinite in Web Api 2.0 ApiController

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-web-api2, nested-loops

I am stuck at the end to find code for Web Api 2.0 (Request and Response) in Get or Post Method BODY.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?
I want to make body JSON loop based on Request Body in Postman.

Not yet connect to database, I just want create template code first for Postman.

1. Here my code for `APIcontroller =`

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ABC.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ABC.Controllers
{
    public class Hitung6Controller : ApiController
    {
    [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Hitung7Model minta1)
        {
            var req1 = minta1.DistributorCode;
            var hasil1 = new List<Hitung7Model>();
            var hasil2 = new List<Hitung8Model>();

            if (req1 != null)
            {
                hasil1.Add(new Hitung7Model()
                {
                    rowNested1 = hasil2
                    
                });

                hasil2.Add(new Hitung8Model()
                {
                });
            }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, minta1);
        }
```

2. Here my code `Models =`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ABC.Models
{
    public class Hitung7Model
    {
        public string DistributorCode { get; set; }
        public List<Hitung8Model> rowNested1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hitung8Model
    {
        public string ProductCode2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3. I try to type Read Request many to many (`ProductCode2`) like this,
   but the Return only 1 (`ProductCode2`):

[image: image1]

In postman I type =

```json
{
    "DistributorCode" : "Abc",
     "rowNested1": [
         {
          "ProductCode2" : "A1",
          "ProductCode2" : "A2"
         }
     ]
}
```

but the Return Response like this =

```json
{
    "DistributorCode": "Abc",
    "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A2"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. I try Read Request body like this, but I get error in Postman and error in `APiController` class
   also get null reference.

[image: image2-Read Request]

Also I want to return infinite / unlimited  loop (`ProductCode2`) for example I type Read Request.
In Postman Read Request:

```
[ProductCode2 = "A1"] until [ProductCode2 = "A100"] 100 row ProductCode2.
```

I need Return Response Nested loop exactly same like Read Request.
in Postman Return Response:

```
[ProductCode2 = "A1"] loop until [ProductCode2 = "A100"] 100 row ProductCode2.
```

I type Postman Read Request, get error amd null reference.

```json
{
    "DistributorCode": "Abcd",
    "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A1"
        }
    ]
    "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A2"
        }
    ]
     "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need return Response structure same as like, Read Request, nested loop infinite ("ProductCode2"):

[image: image3-return Response]

```json
{
    "DistributorCode": "Abcd",
    "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A1"
        }
    ]
    "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A2"
        }
    ]
     "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2": "A3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please can someone try to help me to solved my problem?

Comment: The main problem is your JSON, not the Web-API parts.  I suggest you use something like [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to determine the *valid* JSON you actually want to send and receive first.  Your examples are all not valid JSON, mostly due to duplicated keys.  Postman is showing you this in your image as well.

Comment: in ( WebApiConfig.cs ) i add config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));    so it can do json in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of issues here:

1. Correctly formatting your request body.
2. Getting the information out of the request in the controller.

Let's deal with the request body first, your models are showing you have a single `Hitung7Model` that contains a list of `Hitung8Model` objects as a single field called `rowNested1`. You'll want something like this:

```
{
    "DistributorCode" : "Abc",
    "rowNested1": [
        {
            "ProductCode2" : "A1"
        },
        {
            "ProductCode2" : "A2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now for your controller, you're going to have one instance of `Hitung7Model`, and one list of `Hitung8Model`.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Hitung7Model minta1)
{
    var req1 = minta1.DistributorCode;
    // I've left out hasil1 as it's the same as minta1
    var hasil2 = minta1.rowNested1; // This contains the list of Hitung8Model objects, if you want the string values extracted you can use the following line
    var productCode2s = minta1.rowNested1.Select(row => row.ProductCode2).ToList();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, minta1);
}
```

Additionally, if your `Hitung8Model` is only going to contain a single string value, perhaps it's not needed at all, and you can just have a list of strings on your `Hitung7Model`, so the following:

```
public class Hitung7Model
{
    public string DistributorCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductCodes { get; set; }
}
```

Which would mean you can use the following request body:

```
{
    "DistributorCode" : "Abc",
    "ProductCodes": [
        "A1",
        "A2"
    ]
}
```

And simplify the controller accordingly, i.e. you no longer need that `Select(...)` clause to get the product codes, and could just use `var productCodes = minta1.ProductCodes;`.

Comment: Thank You David, you right that my fault getting wrong type Request body in postman, i try again that the source of my problem, also thanks for solution call assign List in class models.